# in next.js 13.4 why useRouter dosen't contain query?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I passed the query but it's not working in the userRouter hook. when I console.log then it doesn't show any pathname or query parameters.

```
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setProduct(router.query);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  console.log(product);
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={product.image} alt='productImg' />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```